# access outer element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dhtml

I have an issue where I need to know what the outer li element is within the example here using jquery.  Is this possible please?

http://jsfiddle.net/f5HHj/2/

Thanks,
James

Comment: What do you mean by "outer `li` element"? By the way, your fiddle contains syntax errors and doesn't make your question any clearer as far as I can work out!

Comment: your question is not clear james!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the .parent() function you can get the parents of an HTML element, see my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f5HHj/3/

```
$('.Box a').click(function() {
    alert('You clicked a link in the ' + $(this).parent().parent().attr('class') + ' list item.');                                           
})
```

Comment: although in my local solution it doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. See [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$(".some-element-in-li").click(function(){
    var $li = $(this).closest("li");
});
```